# Combinatorics & Cupcakes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $10$ cupcakes left over after a birthday party: $3$ vanilla, $2$ red velvet, and $5$ chocolate. Each of the $8$ guests can take home as many of the cupcakes as they want. How many ways can they do this if together, supposing that they end up taking all the cupcakes?

Comment: I was thinking I could order the cupcakes and the guests. Then I could multiply all possible orderings of the cupcakes (vvvrrcccc, vvrrcccccv, etc) by the number of possible partitions of a given ordering, and multiply that by all possible orderings of the 8 guests. (for a partition, the cupcakes in the nth group would be given to the nth guest). But I think that's overkill since in some case there could be 10 groups in a partition but only 8 guests.

Comment: The suggestion of Henning Makholm is good. To distribute all 5 $\color{brown}{chocolate}$ cupcakes among 8 guest he used the formula ${k+n -1} \choose k $. k are the number of  cupcakes (balls) $k=5$. And $n=8$ is the number of guest (bins). This can also be done for $k=3$ (vanilla) and $k=2$ (red velvet).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Distribute each type of cupcake among the guests separately, and then multiply. For example, distributing the 5 chocolate cupcakes among the 8 guests is a standard stars-and-bars problem with $\binom{12}{5}$ choices.